How to enable Hot Reload in ASP.NET Core 7 web site project
I'm looking to enable Hot Reload to hopefully allow edits to *.cs and/or *.cshtml files without restarting debug cycle.
My original configurations in tasks.json and launch.json are as follows and everything worked (without Hot Reload)...after the site built and started, it found the log entry in terminal and launched the site with the uriFormat argument in a new/clean Chrome instance and all debugging working as expected.
Original tasks.json:
{
    "label": "debug",
    "hide": true,
    "command": "dotnet",
    "type": "process",
    "presentation": {
        "clear": true
    },
    "args": [
        "build", "${input:projectFile}",
        "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
        "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
    ],
    "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
},

Original launch.json:
{
    "name": "Site",
    "presentation": {
        "order": 1,
        "group": "1. L@W Connect"
    },
    "type": "coreclr",
    "request": "launch",
    "preLaunchTask": "debug",
    "logging": {
        "moduleLoad": false
    },
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/net7.0/Nexgen.dll",
    "args": [],
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "stopAtEntry": false,            
    "serverReadyAction": {
        "action": "debugWithChrome",                              
        "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)",
        "uriFormat": "%s/app/channel-home?aws=1&lp=0&datasource=1&showinspector=1&apidebug=ApiProxy_,RBLe_,DocGen_&rblcache=1&tracekatapp=0&sitekey=GOLD",
        "killOnServerStop": true
    },
    "sourceFileMap": {
        "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
    },
    "launchSettingsProfile": "Site"            
},

I modified these files (with advice from Github Copilot) with the following.
New tasks.json:

New label
New args
Added isBackground
New presentation settings

{
    "label": "watch",
    "command": "dotnet",
    "type": "process",
    "args": [
        "watch",
        "run",
        "--project",
        "${input:projectFile}"
    ],
    "problemMatcher": "$msCompile",
    "isBackground": true,
    "presentation": {
        "reveal": "always",
        "panel": "shared"
    }
}

New launch.json:

serverReadyAction.action and serverReadyAction.uriFormat changed
Removed launchSettingsProfile (which is used by devs in Visual Studio proper)

{
    "name": "Site",
    "type": "coreclr",
    "request": "launch",
    "preLaunchTask": "watch",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/net7.0/Nexgen.dll",
    "args": [],
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "stopAtEntry": false,
    "serverReadyAction": {
        "action": "openExternally",
        "pattern": "Now listening on: (https?://\\S+)",
        "uriFormat": "%s"
    },
    "env": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
    },
    "sourceFileMap": {
        "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
    }
},

When I try to launch with updated settings, I get a dialog stating (even though there is a problemMatcher defined):

The task 'watch' has not exited and doesn't have a 'problemMatcher' defined. Make sure to define a problem matcher for watch tasks.
[Debug Anyway] [Configure Task] [Cancel]

In the terminal window, my logging is as follows:
dotnet watch  Hot reload enabled. For a list of supported edits, see https://aka.ms/dotnet/hot-reload.   Press "Ctrl + R" to restart.
dotnet watch  Building...
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  Camelot.Abstractions.Api.Contracts.WebService.Proxy -> c:\BTR\Camelot\Abstractions\Api.Contracts\WebService.Proxy\src\bin\Debug\net7.0\KAT.Camelot.Abstractions.Api.Contracts.WebService.Proxy.dll
  Camelot.Abstractions.Api.Contracts.DataLocker -> c:\BTR\Camelot\Abstractions\Api.Contracts\DataLocker\src\bin\Debug\net7.0\KAT.Camelot.Abstractions.Api.Contracts.DataLocker.dll
  Camelot.Abstractions.RBLe -> c:\BTR\Camelot\Abstractions\RBLe\bin\Debug\net7.0\KAT.Camelot.Abstractions.RBLe.dll
  Camelot.Abstractions.Api.Contracts.RBLe -> c:\BTR\Camelot\Abstractions\Api.Contracts\RBLe\src\bin\Debug\net7.0\KAT.Camelot.Abstractions.Api.Contracts.RBLe.dll 
  Camelot.Domain -> c:\BTR\Camelot\Core\Domain\src\bin\Debug\net7.0\KAT.Camelot.Domain.dll
  Camelot.Infrastructure -> c:\BTR\Camelot\Core\Infrastructure\src\bin\Debug\net7.0\KAT.Camelot.Infrastructure.dll
  Camelot.Telemetry -> c:\BTR\Camelot\Core\Telemetry\src\bin\Debug\net7.0\KAT.Camelot.Telemetry.dll
  Camelot.Data -> c:\BTR\Camelot\Core\Data\src\bin\Debug\net7.0\KAT.Camelot.Data.dll
  Camelot.Domain.Web -> c:\BTR\Camelot\Core\Domain.Web\src\bin\Debug\net7.0\KAT.Camelot.Domain.Web.dll
  Camelot.Telemetry.Web -> c:\BTR\Camelot\Core\Telemetry.Web\src\bin\Debug\net7.0\KAT.Camelot.Telemetry.Web.dll
  Camelot.Infrastructure.Web -> c:\BTR\Camelot\Core\Infrastructure.Web\src\bin\Debug\net7.0\KAT.Camelot.Infrastructure.Web.dll
  Nexgen -> c:\BTR\Camelot\Websites\Nexgen\bin\Debug\net7.0\Nexgen.dll
dotnet watch  Started
[22:24:28 INF] Now listening on: https://localhost:7058 <s:Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime>
dotnet watch  Unable to launch the browser. Navigate to https://localhost:7058 <s:Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime>
[22:24:28 INF] Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down. <s:Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime>
[22:24:28 INF] Hosting environment: Development <s:Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime>    
[22:24:28 INF] Content root path: c:\BTR\Camelot\Websites\Nexgen <s:Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime>

How can I enable Hot Reload?

...is Hot-Reload (and/or Edit-and-Continue) actually supported by VSCode? I found postings where people say it isn't supported in VSC and you need to use the full-fat VS2022 for that.

You might be right.  Github issue here.

In VS code you can open the terminal and run command "dotnet watch run" which will provide you similar functionality.

You can reference this issue: ASP.NET Core with VS Code, can't run the application without debugging enabled

I get the same results...'Unable to launch the browser. Navigate to https://localhost:7058 <s:Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime>'

My version is 1.93. You can try to update your version  or use VS2022. Update websit:https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_93
